# DynamoDB or Hive for data dump processing

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive

I have big data dump. Planning to upload AWS DynamoDB using batch insert. 
Which flow option is cost effective:

1. Big Data (GiB) -> Batch insert to DynamoDB -> Query for analysis
2. Big Data (GiB) -> AWS S3 -> create hive table mapping -> EMR Hive Query for analysis [Without Dynamo DB]

In DynamoDB, is there any throughput limitation if accessed from EMR or EC2?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use DynamoDB for this. Go for option 2 and upload your data into S3 and then do your Hive query.

There is a configurablelimit on how much DynamoDB read capacity EMR will use.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this depends on what you're trying to optimize, if anything, in Hive. If you want to use ORC Files, then you might want to look at DynamoDB a bit. ORC Files require you to double load the data. First you have to load the data into a staging table. Then you have to select from that stage and insert into the ORC File table. This effectively makes you carry the data twice.

If you're not going to optimize the data load, then you might want to look more into @seedhead's response.